# Simplify an integral that resembles Fourier transform

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-transform, complex-integration

I have encountered a formulation simplification problem in engineering.

Consider integral:
$$h(x) = \left| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\! e^{\mathrm{j} x \omega} F(\omega) e^{\mathrm{j} g(x - t\omega)} \, \mathrm{d} \omega \right|^2$$
where $x$ and $\omega$ are Fourier duals in $\mathbb{C}$, $F(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$, $g(x)$ is an unknown function in $\mathbb{R}$, and $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

The engineering problem is, given $h(x)$, $|f(x)|^2$ and $t$, estimate $g(x)$.

I know:

1. If $g(x-t\omega) = \text{const}$, $h(x) = |f(x)|^2$.
2. If linearize $g(x-t\omega)$ as:

   $$g(x - t\omega) \approx g(x) - t g'(x) \omega$$
   then
   $$ h(x) = \left| e^{\mathrm{j} g(x)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\! e^{\mathrm{j} [x - tg'(x)] \omega} F(\omega) \, \mathrm{d} \omega \right|^2 = \left| f(x - tg'(x)) \right|^2 $$
   i.e. consequence of the phase-shift theorem in Fourier transforms. By tracking the movements between case 1 and case 2, $g'(x)$ can be obtained, follow by an integration to get $g(x)$. However this model is not accurate for larger $\omega$ because $t\omega$ will be significantly large beyond locality, thus this linearization simplification is only valid for low frequencies (i.e. small $\omega$'s).

My questions:

- Except doing linearization, what else can I do to simplify the original integral? A neat formulation for probable estimation for $g(x)$ is preferable.
- If linearization is the only way, how should I deal with the higher frequencies (large $\omega$'s)?

Comment: If we absorb the $x\omega$ into the definition of $g$, the integral seems to fit the pattern of integrals that can be tackled by the [stationary phase approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation). The value of the integral is then totally dominated by its behaviour around the stationary points of the (modified) $g$ function. This may not be good news, from the viewpoint of inverting the problem and estimating $g$ from a knowledge of $h$. But at least it's a way of looking at it.

Comment: @LonelyProf Thanks for the suggestion for which I have never thought of. Yet, there is a difference between the two, in that (speaking in terms of the symbols here) (i) in stationary phase approximation $x$ is _linear_ on the exponential, and is large; whereas (ii) mine is a unknown probably nonlinear function $g(x)$.  But it is a good point, thanks.